# is there a library or a way to feed an object to and get a typescript type or interface implementation for that object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

so I've been working with react and typescript this year and I noticed how difficult it can sometime be to be able to type some complex objects. therefore, I was wondering if there could be a way or a helper function that we could call with an object and be able to return a typescript interface or a type back which we could then use to write it in our code and use it as a type for whenever we are using the object.

Example:
say we have an object as such:

```
const complexObject = {

    "hsl": {
        "h": 118.48101265822783,
        "s": 1,
        "l": 0.5,
        "a": 1
    },
    "hex": "#06ff00",
    "rgb": {
        "r": 6,
        "g": 255,
        "b": 0,
        "a": 1
    },
    "hsv": {
        "h": 118.48101265822783,
        "s": 1,
        "v": 1,
        "a": 1
    },
    "oldHue": 118.48101265822784
}
```

as you can see typing this object could be somewhat troublesome, especially to inexperienced developers like myself. now if there could be a library that we could call in this context `getType` then we could do something like this:

```
getType(complexObject); 

// return 
type complexObject = {
    hex: string;
    hsl: { h: number; s: number; l: number; a: number };
    hsv: { h: number; s: number; v: number; a: number };
    rgb: { r: number; g: number; b: number; a: number };
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to use a type in a file the way you've written `getType` above, use [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) as in [Ozan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72501065/1426891). Though `typeof` works at *runtime* to return a string in standard JavaScript, TypeScript gives `typeof` additional meaning: in a type expression it allows you to reuse the type of an existing identifier.

```
// Runs in the emitted JavaScript.
const someValue = typeof complexObject; // "object"

// Type only: not emitted to JavaScript.
type SomeType = typeof complexObject; // { hsl: { ... }, ... }

// Type only as well, because it's after the : so TS reads it as a type.
const typedValue: typeof complexObject = getComplexObject();
//    field name: type expression      = initial value
```

Remember, types don't exist at runtime, so there isn't ever a chance that you could *return* a type as a runtime value or function return expression like `getType`.
A function like `getType` might return a value, and that value might have a useful type, but you can't return the type itself with a function.

Side note: if you're trying to write a declaration file based on existing JavaScript code, or if you want to get to the interface definition so you can copy-paste it into your own code, a standard tool for that is [dts-gen](https://github.com/microsoft/dts-gen).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function like `getType` to retrieve the type as a variable and reuse it in your code.

All you need to do is using the `typeof` operator and assigning that value to a `type` variable.

```
type ComplexObjectType = typeof complexObject;
```

Now, you can use `ComplexObjectType` as a type to other variables in your project.